# recovering partition in multiboot configuration with tesdisk

Tags: testdisk, partition-recovery

i have a multiboot configuration with three os,suddenly two have become corrupted.
i have read the testdisk guide,but i´m not confident,anybody could help?I have doubts like should select only the partitions that were missing or also the only that remained and should i select the partition that contains the boot manager?